# Why won't .datatables sort properly?

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I am using the jquery plugin .dataTables and cannot get it to sort properly. After reading similar questions on stack overflow I am still confused and need help! I am posting the code below. Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the portion of html for the table:

```
<thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Store Name</th>
        <th>District Manager</th>
        <th>Store ID</th>
        <th>Payday</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Payday/Title Total</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach($bigQuery as $i => $row) {
    $total = $row['mtd_payday'] + $row['mtd_title'];
    echo "<tr>" . "<td>" . $row['store_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td >" . $row['district_manager'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td >" . $row['store_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td data-sort=\"". $row['mtd_payday']. "\">" . money_format('%.2n',  $row['mtd_payday']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td data-sort=\"". $row['mtd_title']. "\">" . money_format('%.2n',  $row['mtd_title']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td data-sort=\"$total\">" . money_format('%.2n',  $total) . "</td>" . "</tr>";
    $total = "";
} ?> 
</tbody>
```

I am populating the table with data from a query. the javascript for the table is below:

```
<script>
//initializes the dataTable plugin. 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#balances').DataTable({
        tableTools: {
            "sSwfPath": "../copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"  
        }
});
var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( table );
$( tt.fnContainer() ).insertBefore('div.dataTables_wrapper');  }); 
</script>
```

I am a new programmer and totally new to the .dataTables plugin. When I try to use the sort buttons at the top of the table, it does not sort properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatables should sort by default. That leads me to believe that there is a problem with your html syntax.

After checking I noticed that your ending `<tr>` in `<thead>` is incorrect. Add the `/` and make it `</tr>`

---

After seeing your picture, it is sorting it and treating the columns as `strings`. In order to change the data-type of a column for sorting, you need to add [`sType`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns#sType) to the columns. The default supported types are string, numeric, date and html.

The code should be changed to:

```
var table = $('#balances').DataTable({
    "aoColumns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "sType": "numeric" },
        { "sType": "numeric" },
        { "sType": "numeric" }
    ],
    tableTools: {
        "sSwfPath": "../copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"  
    }
});
```

Comment: It is correct in my code. I omitted the / when typing it here on accident. I have read that Datatables should sort by default but it is not working.

Comment: When you say "it does not sort properly", does that mean that it is sorting, but just not in the way you expect?

Comment: Yes, it is sorting just not as expected. Let me grab a screenshot and post it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/813ap2lrargwd6w/Screenshot%202014-08-26%2010.10.40.png?dl=0    It should be sorted in descending order, but is not accurate. Part of the table is sorted correctly, but not all of it. I have the totals column sorted in descending order.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/itsj9qqbuhu0cs2/Screenshot%202014-08-26%2010.17.42.png?dl=0 I changed the code as you posted and it completely did away with the arrow boxes to sort! I think this is ALMOST the answer and I am super appreciative. I am going to research a little more, and posted another screenshot of it after the change. thank you for taking a look at this @Ninsly !

Comment: Is a plugin required to use  aoColumns?

Comment: No, aoColumns is part of datatables. The numbers might not be sorting correctly because of the `$` in them. There are plugins for [extra sorting features](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/). [Here is the currency sorting plugin](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/currency) that you might want to use.

Comment: thank you @Ninsly. If this was a productive question I would appreciate an upvote. Your answer was very helpful!